# Embedding an image in an email using linux commands

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

Is there a way to embed images into the body of an email using linux commands like `mutt` or `sendmail`?

I used this

```
mutt -e 'set content_type="text/image"' \
   u.mohan@6dtech.co.in -s "TEST" \
    -i image001.jpg < data.txt
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 5):

I have written a shell script to send with `mutt` an HTML message with embedded images rather than linked ones.

Several steps:

1. download all image files linked by `<img>` tags in the original HTML,
2. prepare the HTML file by changing the `src` url to a `cid`,
3. prepare a multipart e-mail with `(neo)mutt`
4. fix some content description tags in this e-mail
5. send with `sendmail`

Here's the main script which takes the HTML filename as argument (no checks performed, please do not consider it as an alpha software):

```
#!/bin/bash
F=$(basename "$1")
DIR="/tmp/inlinizer-$$/"
mkdir -p $DIR/Img
grep "src=" "$1" | sed -e "s,.*src=\"\([^\"]*/\)*\([^\"/]*\)\".*,wget \1\2 -O $DIR/Img/\2," > $DIR/get_img.sh
bash $DIR/get_img.sh
sed -e 's,src="\([^"]*/\)*\([^"/]*\)",src="cid:\2@example.com",g' < "$1" > "$DIR/$F"
neomutt -e 'set smtp_url=""' -e 'set sendmail="mysendmail"' -e "set content_type=text/html" me@example.com -s "test" -a $DIR/Img/* < "$DIR/$F"
```

One also needs a custom sendmail command (`mysendmail` in the above) which post-processes the e-mail file generated by `mutt`:

```
sed -e 's,Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="\([^"]*\)",Content-Disposition: inline; name="\1"\nContent-ID: <\1@example.com>,' < /dev/stdin | sed -e 's,Content-Type: multipart/mixed;,Content-Type: multipart/related;,' | sendmail $*
```

I have tested it in GMail and a few other webmails. Reports of problems with mail clients or webmails welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can *attach* the image, by changing the **-i** in your command line to a **-a**. This won't embed the image perse, but will include it. If you want to embed it, the mail you send will have to be of content type `text/html` and include an `img` tag to show the attached image.

See this SO page about how to correctly embed image attachments in HTML mail.

[Embedding attached images in HTML emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922898/embedding-attached-images-in-html-emails)

Comment: actually in mutt on option was there to attach files inline using -i but it was not working

Comment: It sounds like `-i` is only for text files for the body of the message.

Comment: am using -a option to attach but i need inline attach asper my requirements

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to send emails with embedded images as part of the email using a bash script, I pieced this code together.

The email is started with these line:

```
EMAILBODY="echo \"Alarm went off! "
EMAILATTACH=""
```

Inside of a loop that defines each file to attach:

```
EMAILATTACH=$EMAILATTACH" -a /home/xyz/"$ID"/"$Event"/"$Frame"-capture.jpg"
EMAILBODY=$EMAILBODY"<BR> <IMG Height=150 SRC=\"$Frame-capture.jpg\">"
```

After the loop, the email is completed with these lines:

```
EMAILBODY=$EMAILBODY"\" | mutt -e \"set content_type=text/html\" -s \"House Alarm went off!\""
EMAILSTRING=$EMAILBODY$EMAILATTACH" -- user@server.net"
eval $EMAILSTRING
```

My last hurdle is that when I receive this on my android phone (maybe the same on other browsers), it doesn't display the picture, only a small box (even after you have downloaded the attachments).  It shows up fine in Outlook though.

Comment: this doesn't work because it misses the Content-ID for the attachment to be linked into the html email.

Answer (score 0):

It's even possible with the basic mail command

You want to create a mime HTML email a la:

[How to embed images in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email/4312865#4312865)

Then take the headers (all the lines before the first boundary), remove them from that input and add them individually with the -a command after mail such as:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262421/2244213
or
[Sending HTML mail using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317174/sending-html-mail-using-a-shell-script/3317304#3317304)

Comment: There is no single universal `mail` comcand with this capability. If yours does; good for you; but for this to be useful to othes, this answer should describe which platform you're on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of the [Joce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1635909/joce)'s [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54536691/1483447).

This one does not require a custom `sendmail` command, because it creates one on the fly, uses it and deletes it afterwards.

It is parametric, so you don't need to change its code for different recipients and the like, and it offers a few other goodies.

The first few lines of code should be clear enough to explain the five positional parameters meaning, but here is an example, just in case:

```
<script.sh> /srv/emailbody.html "Sender's Name" sender@example.com "Embedded images" 'Recipent's name <recipient@example.net>'
```

It depends on `mktemp` (the original script did not), because I like that more than using `$$`, but that's only a matter of taste.

```
#!/bin/bash

HTMLFULLPATH="$1"
SENDER="$2"
SENDEREMAIL="$3"
SUBJECT="$4"
RECIPIENT="$5"

HTML=$(basename "${HTMLFULLPATH}")
SENDERDOMAIN=$(echo "${SENDEREMAIL}" | cut -d@ -f2)

if ! [[ "${RECIPIENT}" == '*<*' ]] ; then
  RECIPIENT="${RECIPIENT}"'<'"${RECIPIENT}"'>' # TO_NO_BRKTS_* SpamAssassin rules
fi

function atexit
{
  rm -rf "${TEMPDIR}" "${NEOMUTTCONFIG}" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

trap atexit INT TERM EXIT

TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
mkdir -p "${TEMPDIR}/img"
grep "src=" "${HTMLFULLPATH}" | sed -e "s,.*src=\"\([^\"]*/\)*\([^\"/]*\)\".*,wget \1\2 -O ${TEMPDIR}/img/\2," > "${TEMPDIR}/getimg.sh"
bash "${TEMPDIR}/getimg.sh" >/dev/null 2>&1
sed -e 's,src="\([^"]*/\)*\([^"/]*\)",src="cid:\2@'${SENDERDOMAIN}'",g' < "${HTMLFULLPATH}" > "${TEMPDIR}/${HTML}"
SENDMAIL="${TEMPDIR}/sendmail.sh"

cat > "${SENDMAIL}" << EOF
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's,Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="\([^"]*\)",Content-Disposition: inline; name="\1"\nContent-ID: <\1@'${SENDERDOMAIN}'>,' < /dev/stdin | sed -e 's,Content-Type: multipart/mixed;,Content-Type: multipart/related;,' | sendmail \$*
EOF

chmod a+rx "${SENDMAIL}"

NEOMUTTCONFIG=$(mktemp)

echo 'set from="'"${SENDER}"' <'"${SENDEREMAIL}"'>"' >> "${NEOMUTTCONFIG}"
echo 'set smtp_url=""' >> "${NEOMUTTCONFIG}"
echo 'set sendmail="'${SENDMAIL}'"' >> "${NEOMUTTCONFIG}"
echo "set content_type=text/html" >> "${NEOMUTTCONFIG}"

neomutt -F "${NEOMUTTCONFIG}" "${RECIPIENT}" -s "${SUBJECT}" -a "${TEMPDIR}/img/"* < "${TEMPDIR}/${HTML}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a command line for this purpose https://github.com/gonejack/embed-email

```sh
go get github.com/gonejack/embed-email
```

```
Usage:
  embed-email *.eml [flags]

Flags:
  -v, --verbose   verbose
  -h, --help      help for embed-email
```

Answer (score -1):

```
EMAILBODY="echo \"Alarm went off! "
EMAILATTACH=""
EMAILATTACH=$EMAILATTACH" -a "/home/uat12mgr/XXDBD_AR_INV_PRINT.jpg""
EMAILBODY=$EMAILBODY"<BR> <IMG Height=150 SRC=\""/home/uat12mgr/XXDBD_AR_INV_PRINT.jpg"\">"
EMAILBODY=$EMAILBODY"\" | mutt -e \"set content_type=text/html\" -s \"House Alarm went off!\""
EMAILSTRING=$EMAILBODY$EMAILATTACH" -- myaka@abc.com"
eval $EMAILSTRING
```

Comment: This is not working for me.
Error in command line: content_type: unknown variable

Comment: It is IIRC from version 1.5.2 something that it was added to mutt