# Include Images in HTML email send from Unix Box

Tags: html, shell, email, unix

I have a script like this which sends html emails. I am trying to include images into my html emails. Is this possible ? File has to use this function. I'm not looking for some quick one liner instead of my function because of file manipulations I have done in my script. When I send out emails I back a [X] instead of my image.

Email function of my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

Email()
{
export MAILTO="ADC@aol.com"
export CONTENT="file"
export SUBJECT="Report"
(
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "To : $MAILTO"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat "$CONTENT"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
}

Email
```

File I am sending "file"

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="/home/admin/Afriendlycow.png">
</body>
</html>
```

I attempt to try just the file name instead of the path such as Afriendlycow.png but it does not work also.

Comment: What if you have your image web-hosted and then so long as there is a web connection the picture should go through

Comment: That's a good idea but I don't think it's possible. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It's quite possible but works poorly when recipients disable remote images.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embeding an image in an email using linux commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381071/embeding-an-image-in-an-email-using-linux-commands)

Answer (score 0):

You are not attaching any images. A proper HTML email with images is a `multipart/related` containing one `text/html` part and one or more `image/*` parts. They should have a `Content-Id:` header with a unique identifier as its value; the HTML refers to them using `<img src="cid:identifier">`.