# Sending image in HTML email

Tags: php, html, email

I send HTML emails with PHP's `mail()` function with this header:

```
$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Now, I want to embed an image. Should I just simply do that as simple as this?

```
<img src="http://www.example.de/images/image.png" alt="test" title="test" />
```

With this, a warning is shown if you open the email in Outlook etc., that images from an external server are embedded. Is it possible/better to use base64 encode like this?

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,..." alt="test" title="test" />
```

Or are data URIs not supported by mail programs widely?

---

EDIT: Thank you for voting for close, because this question is "opinion-based". I do not think so, because I asked for this:

> Or are data URIs not supported by mail programs widely?

I need a possibility for sending images in emails without loading them from my server. And I just want to know of any disadvantages or other methods.

Comment: I've found similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed images in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data URI's are supported in [some email clients](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9330720/222245).

The best way to include images in your HTML email is probably to [include them as separate parts, referenced by their content id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/922905/222245):

```
<img src="cid:123456789" alt="Attached image">
```

Also have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018709/how-to-create-an-email-with-embedded-images-that-is-compatible-with-the-most-mai)