# Embedding attached data in MIME, to the HTML portion of the email. Not linking to the attached file

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, mime, amazon-ses

I have generated this MIME data, that is sent through aws-ses. Here in the entire MIME data

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=T4nu9J8b
From: <noreply@noreply.in>
To: <myemail@gmail.com>
Subject: Your Image

--T4nu9J8b
Content-Type: multipart/alternate;boundary=R5I0TJcF

--R5I0TJcF
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8

<h1> Hi!!! </h1><p>Here is your progress report </p><br/> <img alt="Embedded Image" src="cid:testimage.png"/>
--R5I0TJcF
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

This is the plain text version of the message.
--R5I0TJcF--
--T4nu9J8b
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment ;filename="testimage.png"

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...
--T4nu9J8b--
```

I receive the email, but the image isn't embedding into the html part of the MIME
The img tag is linked to the attached file

HTML CODE

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="cid:testimage.png"/>
```

MIME attachment

```
--T4nu9J8b Content-Type: image/png Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment ;filename="testimage.png"

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...
--T4nu9J8b--
```

RESULTING EMAIL

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image attachment section needs Content-ID

```
--T4nu9J8b
Content-Type: image/png
Content-ID: <idname>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment ;filename="testimage.png"

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...
--T4nu9J8b--
```

> Note: Content-ID name should be put in an angular bracket, as given

Embed it into  tag using same Content-ID (without the angular bracket)

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="cid:idname"/>
```

This should allow the attach image to be displayed into the html!

Complete resource: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2387.html

Question similar to
[Embedding attached images in HTML emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922898/embedding-attached-images-in-html-emails)
But I couldn't find an accurate answer. I'll post the same there too.