# I'm not able to add an image in email body using email.message in python

Tags: python, image, email, html-email

```
import smtplib
import email.message

def sent_email(From,email,passw):  
    body = f"""
    <p>Text blabla </p>
    <img src="image_name.jpg" alt="loading problem" width=400 height=560>
    """

    msg = email.message.Message()
    msg['Subject'] = "subject"
    msg['From'] = From
    msg['To'] = email
    password = passw
    msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    msg.set_payload(body )

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
    s.starttls()
    # Login Credentials for sending the mail
    s.login(msg['From'], password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To']], msg.as_string().encode('utf-8'))
    print('Email sent')
```

The email is sent, but the image does not appear. The message "loading problem" appears.

Just found how to attach. I want it in the body of the email.

Comment: Have you tried attaching the image, i.e. `msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='image_name.jpg')` and/or ` msg.add_attachment(*args, content_manager=None, **kw)¶`?  Your html render the page, but you to have access to the image?  The other option is to use a remote url if your email service allows it.  I would also look at a working example and see how your email compares.

Comment: I have access to image. msg.add_header(...)  attaches the image. But not in the body of the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be as simple as uploading the image to a publicly accessible webserver, and using the full path to it, i.e. not `src="image_name.jpg"` but rather `src="https://www.imageserver.com/folder/image_name.jpg"`

Comment: Thank you very much. Very simple and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to link to an attached image in an email, you have to use a special URL that starts with "cid:".  Check here:

[Embedding attached images in HTML emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922898/embedding-attached-images-in-html-emails)

Comment: This is not the best way forward. Not all email applications support this method which uses base64 encoding, see https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about.  I'm talking about an image attached as a separate MIME section, and an image tag with `src="cid:myimage.png"`.  That's in RFC 1813 and support is nearly universal.

Comment: Ok, it appears CID doesn't necessarily base64 encode. However, it is correct to say not all email applications support this method - particularly webmail. As reported by SendGrid https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/ and MailTrap https://mailtrap.io/blog/embedding-images-in-html-email-have-the-rules-changed/